# MapInfo Custom Projection to PROJ4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapinfo

Just getting into QGIS and coming from MapInfo. I have some custom projections that I would like transferred. I've been trying to figure out the parameters today without any luck. I have the following from MapInfo.

```
> 8 = Transverse Mercator 62 = North American 1927 8 = US Survey Feet
> -115.5833333333002 = latitude Origin
> 34.75 = Longitude Origin
> 0.9999 = Scale
> 499999.999998 = false easting
> -999999.9999960001 = false northing
```

Thought this would work in QGIS but it doesn't.

```
+proj=tmerc 
+datum=NAD27
+units=ft
+centerLat=-115.5833333333002
+centerLong=34.75
+k_0=0.9999
+x_0=499999.999998
+y_0=-999999.9999960001
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Guess: According to MapInfo doc, false easting/northing are in the units of the coordsys. In PROJ (used in QGIS), they're in meters. Also switch centerLat/centerLong to +lat_0 and +lon_0 AND swap the values. -115 is a longitude, not a latitude.

Comment: Thanks Mkennedy. Stupid me didn't recognize the lat long swap. I made the changes you suggested and still it didn't make a conversion. Is there a specific order of the parameters that I am missing? Here is what I have now. +proj=tmerc +datum=NAD27 +units=m +lat_0=34.75 +lon_0=-115.5833333333002 +k_0=0.9999 +x_0=499999.999998 +y_0=-999999.9999960001

Comment: Shouldn't the units still be feet? If so, I think they should be `+units=ftUS`, not just `+units=ft`.